# Using Phonegap CLI - Barcode scanner not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-cli

I developing an app for iOS and Android using PhoneGap 3.4.0 from the command line interface, and want to make use of the BarcodeScanner plugin. The problem is that the scanner does not actually do anything when called by my app. The camera does not come up. By using console.log with Safari developer tools, I can tell that the scan function does exist and is getting called... it just isn't doing anything.

I installed the scanner plugin like this:
`phonegap plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner`

In the index.html, included the javascripts like this:

```
  <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
  <script src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
```

In config.xml, added this:

`<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />`

When I set scanner variable like this it logs that there is a BarcodeScanner, and it does have a function `scan`, but then when I call the function `scan` nothing happens. (the camera does not open).

```
var scanner = cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner;
console.log(scanner)  // =>  BarcodeScanner
```

This is how I'm calling the `scan` function:

```
scanner.scan( function (result) {
  ... my code here...
} );
```

Any ideas? I'd really appreciate any help or pointers in how to get the barcodeScanner to work with PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the version from wildabeast was not compatible with PhoneGap >= 3.2.0.

Use this branch instead: https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner

Install with

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner
```

To get it to work, I had to create a brand new app, copy the www folder over, and then install the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I´m having the exact same problem.

After I updated my App to support arm64 (iPad Air), I ran into this issue.

A work-a-round:

1. Push the hardware <kbd>On/Off</kbd> button.
2. Turn on the device again.
3. Try starting the barcodeScanner.

This worked for me - but the App will not leave my desk before the issue has been fixed properly.

The issue now exists on all of my devices (iPad Mini, iPhone 4S, iPad Air).

Comment: It must be a different issue for me. I tried this but it didn't work.